# How can I center my ul li list inside my div?

Tags: html, css

I have the following page http://jsfiddle.net/Leytgm3L/18/ and as you can see there are 6 links to different cities. I put a following css:

```
.cities-main  li {
        float: none;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        margin-right: 10%;
        list-style: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
```

to spread this list horizontally, but the problem is that it's not center inside the main div... How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding these rules:

```
.cities-main{ padding: 0; text-align: center; }
.cities-main > li:last-child{ margin-right: 0; }
```

By doing so, the last link won’t break into a new line due to its `margin-right`. Also, the first link will be on the left border of its parent element. And altogether their centered.

Here’s a fiddle with it: http://jsfiddle.net/04z3L5gs/

Answer (score 5):

In order to center your list of cities, simply apply the following to your ul:

```
ul {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: yes, thanks, that did the trick! I'll accept it as soon as I can :)

Comment: Thanks! But take a look at (and accept) @dakab 's answer: it's better :)

Comment: @AndreaJessup: Thank you madam,
your decoration of [sportsmanship](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/805/sportsmanship) will have been proven to be well-founded.

Answer (score 0):

Well , usually centering elements depends on the dimension of the element.

Try to gradually change the left and right margins , so that it is located where you want. That for the code you have right now.

But I recommend that you use:

```
.cities-main  li {
        float: none;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        margin-right: 10%;
        list-style: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: 400;
        position: relative;
        left: 50px;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
```

Modifies magnitude of element "left:50px" until you're satisfied.

Also consider whether you should use "margin-right:10%"